# MPTCP doesn't create multiple subflows

Tags: tcp

I've installed MCTCP in one machine, and tested it in https://amiusingmptcp.com which  gave a positive result. Now, when I do `iperf -c multipath-tcp.org` like they say [here](http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php?n=Users.UseMPTCP) I only see one connection:

```
root@user:~# netstat -m
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       Local Token Remote Token
mptcp      0 602616 streaming.local:47914   mptcp.info.ucl.ac.:5001 ESTABLISHED 2590462875  3979247341
```

and iperf shows the same, one connection:

```
root@user:~# iperf -c multipath-tcp.org
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to multipath-tcp.org, TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  512 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.1.11 port 47914 connected with 130.104.230.45 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.3 sec  6.75 MBytes  5.48 Mbits/sec
```

What should I do more to divide the data between multiple subflows?

**EDIT:**

To make MPTCP work I simply installed Debian Wheezy and downloaded the package they have precompiled for that distribution.

I tried it with this `sysctl` tweaks;
`net.mptcp.mptcp_path_manager=fullmesh`, `ndiffports` and `binder` (?)
`net.mptcp.mptcp_scheduler=roundrobin` and `default`
`net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = cubic` and `olia`

I didn't rebooted each time I made those changes, but I think that is not mandatory because when I changed to `binder`, a `binder registered` message appeared in `dmesg`.

Also installed their tools and made:

```
ip link set dev eth0 multipath off
ip link set dev wlan0 multipath on
ip link set dev wwan0 multipath on
```

Btw, `eth0` is unplugged, but just in case.

the output of `ip route`:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  proto static
169.254.0.0/16 dev wwan0  scope link  metric 1000
192.168.0.0/24 dev wwan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.100
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.11
```

**EDIT2:**

I've removed the 3g router and connected to my normal router via Ethernet and WiFi, so I have now 2 interfaces with Internet: `wlan0` and `eth2`. Also I've added the autorouting scripts named [here](http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/ConfigureRouting) at the bottom (mptcp_up and mptcp_down), so the routings changed to this:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.217
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.11
```

But the connections still don't make multiple subflows. `iperf` and `netstat -m` still returns 1 connection.

NOTE: I removed 3g router and added eth0 connection because the router was giving me problems, but I still have multiple interfaces to test the subflows.

Comment: Sorry for my unfamiliarity with MPTCP, but what does it mean that "you gave positive"?

Comment: There are many prerequisities for MPTCP, so you will need to share your network configuration, especially kernel version (and patches) and the output of `ip route`. Would be good to share all the steps you did to make MPTCP work.

Comment: @Anthon, that website tells you if you are connecting to the website via MPTCP or not, with "and gave positive" I was meaning "the website gave positive", not "I gave positive" xD.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda, added the info, but with "kernel info with patches" I don't know what you are talking about. I have the kernel that came with MPTCP that they give away: 3.14.27.wheezymptcp

Comment: That about 3.14.27.wheezymptcp is exactly what I was asking about. Where exactly does it come from?

Comment: I have the same problem on Android. Instead of netstat, I monitor  /proc/net/dev and all the tx/rx packets are going through wlan0 (both rmnet0 and wlan0 are active)

Comment: @Ashkan Did you have any progress? I seem to be stuck at the same place.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shared enough information to show that your machine has dual connectivity that could in turn be used for two different MPTCP channels. But as I believe you attempted to give enough information, I can deduce that you don't know the prerequisities and therefore I think I can give you an answer. I'm not actually using MPTCP and others may give you better answers.

Multipath TCP is useful when one of the endpoints can talk to the other via different routes. In your case you seem to suggest that your machine is the endpoint that can be reachable via multiple routes but I'm not convinced your machine is set up so that it can actually work that way.

First of all, you would need to use source based routing. Some examples are given in the [feature request for NetworkManager to support creating a source based routing configuration](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=709478). Second, it's hard to reach your machine from outside if it has private network addresses hidden behind a masquerading (NAT) router. MPTCP works well on devices connected to the Internet, not on those connected to private networks with limited connectivity through a masquerading router.

If you just want to experiment, you might have better luck with using just one connection to reach a MPTCP capable endpoint via two different routes. But if you want to span connection over two different connections on your side, you'd probably first have to get two *real* links to the Internet with one public IPv4 or IPv6 address each.

You said that some websites indicate that you have MPTCP support. You should check with those websites what exactly that means. It can be just that your system reports MPTCP support to them which doesn't say anything about the number of channels you can start. It could also be that you can communicate over one interface but can use multiple channels if the website is available via multiple addresses.

Comment: Altough this is a pretty good answer, this is not what is really hapening. MPTCP simply divides a TCP connection between multiple routes, provided that both ends has MPTCP protocol installed. I've installed and configured MPTCP in my machine and the server that I was pointing to with `iperf` is a server with MPTCP enabled too, so only with that it should start working the good way, as described here: http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php?n=Users.UseMPTCP

Comment: Now I've started discovering what happens. It seems that subflows are created, but they are not shown in `netstat m`, because when I enable/disable an interface to use MPTCP I note variations in the bandwith, but because my bandwith isn't stable per se is difficult to troubleshoot it. I'm going to work more on it. Thank you for your details! :-)

Comment: The routing was simply a desperate measure xD

Comment: AFAIK it only uses multiple subchannels if one of the endpoint is reachable via multiple interfaces but if you have any specific link saying otherwise, please let me know.